# not found (404) error in dnn

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, installation

I have created a module named "Module Example" on cristoc for dnn and after build that I want to make the release of that module. It show me an error below.

```
Error   2   The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module Example\\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module Example\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Then I have to try some nuggets to Install like "nuget install packages.config" and "Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json". After installing both nugets, click on build and make release of this module and release created successfully at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Module Example\install` and release name `Module_Example_00.00.01_Source` it is a zip folder. After that for installing this module on dnn environment, I open my dnn site "dnndev.me" and after login on it, hover on host and click on extension and after that click on Install extension button and browse the location of the folder and click on "Next" button. But after that an error occur on installing this module.

```
Failure     File specified in the dnn could not be found in the zip file: - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\dnndev.me\Install\Temp\1cjkvd5v\bin\Module_Example.dll
```

And my on DNN environment `Not found(404)` error also comes. Why? I don't understand what happens. Kindly suggest me waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know those components but I think the generated package is a source package inspite of the release package you're waiting for.
Then, it probably doesn't contain the corresponding generated assembly. I suggest you to open the zip to verify the presence of "Module_Example.dll".
Does this dll exist in your development environnment? Does your ascx use "codebehind" or "codefile"? With codefile mode, you don't need to upload the dll but the source file (vb.net ou C#).
I  hope it helps you.